# Подскажите, как можно форматировать символы по отдельности в .docx на python

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

Суть такая, что надо выставить разные шрифты каждому символу в тексте

как я понял что python-docx для этого не подходит

Comment: OpenXML попробуй.